# ASA5505 :: Access-list permit public ip on port list (not range)

Tags: cisco-asa, static-routes, access-control-list

This is likely a common issue, but cannot find a solution.

Here's the problem:
in web server environment there are a set of common ports that need to be open, to name a few: 21,25,53,80,110,143,3306, etc.

I know how to create an access-list to allow an external ip on a given port and a static rule to direct port traffic to target internal ip. However, man, that is a lot of drudgery doing single ip + single port rules when you have 15 public IPs all of which need the exact same 20-odd ports open.

Is there a way to per public ip specify an access-list of ports and a corresponding static rule?? Basically I'd like to pull this off in 30 lines ( 15 public ips X (1 access-list + 1 static) ) vs 600!

Ideas much appreciated (in this case, obviously) ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object groups are your friend here. Assuming a worst case scenario where your public address block is non contiguous and there is not a direct subnet mapping onto your private subnet, and that your outside access list has the default name of **outside_access_in** you'll need a configuration along the lines of...

```
object-group network my-servers_pub
network-object host 1.1.1.1
network-object host 1.1.1.3
network-object host 1.1.1.5
...etc
...etc
network-object host 1.1.1.13
network-object host 1.1.1.15

object-group service my-tcp-ports tcp
port-object eq 21
port-object eq 25
port-object eq 80
port-object eq 110
port-object eq 143
port-object eq 3306

object-group service my-udp-ports udp
port-object eq 53

static (inside,outside) 1.1.1.1 192.168.1.2
static (inside,outside) 1.1.1.3 192.168.1.4
static (inside,outside) 1.1.1.5 192.168.1.7
...etc
...etc
static (inside,outside) 1.1.1.13 192.168.1.14
static (inside,outside) 1.1.1.15 192.168.1.16

access-list outside_access_in permit tcp any object-group my-servers_pub object-group my-tcp-ports
access-list outside_access_in permit udp any object-group my-servers_pub object-group my-udp-ports
```

I should caveat that this configuration will need some tweaking to work on ASA version 8.3 and above due to some significant changes Cisco have made around natting.

If you're lucky enough to have contiguous public address space, and a 1:1 host mapping you can condense down the object groups & statics into subnets:

```
object-group network my-servers_pub
network-object 1.1.1.0 255.255.255.240

static (inside,outside) 1.1.1.0 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.240
```

You wouldn't even really need the object group for your outside hosts in this scenario, but i've done it that way just to keep it consistent.

Comment: I'm on ASA 8.2, so no problem there.  This looks quite concise. Public ips will all map linearly to 172.16.xx.xx dmz.  Should do the trick, but I need to test obviously. Evryone gets a +1 so far as everyone is right (in their own way) ;-)

Comment: You'll be able to condense it down a bit further with some subnetting then:

Comment: gets the nod here, his answer was the most comprehensive and accurate (although it's "network-object", not "network object"). If you have a dmz you'll need to adjust static rule accordingly (e.g. static(dmz,outside) ). Works a charm, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `static` to map IPs 1-to-1. Like this:

```
static (inside,outside) 1.2.3.1 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.255
static (inside,outside) 1.2.3.2 192.168.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.255
static (inside,outside) 1.2.3.3 192.168.0.3 netmask 255.255.255.255
```

<sub>(These could be condensed if the mapping is in order like the example)</sub>

Then have a single access list such as:

```
access-list Outside_In ext permit tcp any any eq 21
access-list Outside_In ext permit tcp any any eq 25
access-list Outside_In ext permit tcp any any eq 53

access-group Outside_In in int Outside
```

Warning! This will open all the ports to all mapped IPs. If all your servers need these ports anyway, then it's a much quicker configuration.

<sub>(Obviously change names of things as is appropriate for your site)</sub>

Comment: Ahh, that's better, had been doing acls on per ip basis. Yes, each public ip needs the same ports opened, so not concerned (or at least not as much as relying on ip tables alone without a physical firewall ;-)) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok for the access list you can use object-groups to make lump them in together.

```
object-group network TAG
 network-object 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.255
 network-object 192.168.1.3 255.255.255.255
 network-object 192.168.1.4 255.255.255.255
 network-object 192.168.1.5 255.255.255.255

object-group protocol PROTO_TAG
 protocol-object tcp 80

access-list NAT_ME permit ip object-group TAG eq object-group PROTO_TAG 

static (outside,inside) IP access-list NAT_ME
```

Fair warning I have not tested this on anything. It's what the documentation says should work.

Comment: I'll have to give that a try, looks reasonable.

Comment: This is a bit more abstract compared to standard ACL + static rule, but if it works, and does so efficiently, I'm game ;-).  Going to try Chris' solution first, but both get +1 from here